# ARM11 Linux Simulator

Tags: debugging, assembly, raspberry-pi, simulator, armv6

Basically, I have been learning ARM assembly language on my Raspberry Pi for the past few months, and so now that my programs are getting a little more complex, I am starting to feel the need to debug my code more often. Is there an ARM11 simulator running on Linux I can use?

Comment: QEMU can probably do that.

Comment: QEMU will let me virtualize a Raspberry Pi OS onto my own computer. What I really need is a GUI assembler that would at least let me walk through my machine code for debugging purposes

Comment: Alright. If you just want a debugger for ARM/Linux that would probably be `gdb`. I'm not familiar with any GUI front-ends for `gdb` though (maybe `ddd` supports ARM?).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a debugger, not a simulator. You should be able to remote-gdb to the board, or if you want to go whole hog, get yourself a USB->JTAG/SDI adapter and you can debug at the bare-metal level.